# Clone one branch without history but allow pulling/checkout other branches on demand? ("lazy" git workflow)

Tags: git

I am working with a large repo and am looking for ways to improve my workflow as it takes a long time to clone/pull/fetch.

I'd like to essentially implement a "lazy" or "on demand" git workflow - downloading things as I need them. Happy to use multiple git commands (and perhaps wrapping those in utility shell functions)

My objectives are:

- Clone only the `main` branch of the repo in its current state, ignoring history (or at least not downloading anything relating to the history)
- Only download a branch when I deliberaltely check out the branch from the remote
- Running `git pull` to only pull the changes for the branches I have available locally - if this spans multiple commands, I am happy to wrap this in a shell function.

I am experimenting with this approach. To clone the repo:

```
git clone -b main --depth 1 --no-single-branch git@... myfolder
```

I believe `-b` will clone the single branch, `--depth` will ignore history and `--no-single-branch` will allow me to checkout other branches - though I am not 100% sure.

It appears that running `git pull` still fetches changes from the remote/I guess updating the list of branches available at origin?

To checkout a new branch I do the following:

```
git pull origin target-branch
git checkout target-branch
```

I'm not overly familiar with git's options, but would this do what I am hoping for?